# SSH Authentication using Windows Active Directory

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-authentication, ssh-keys, openssh

I have a set of files that are located on a file server(File1) with I want to transfer to an Application Server(App1) using SSH. I have setup authentication on the File1, but it happens only for local user accounts. I want to improvise the authentication by using Active Directory, I have set of AD-One groups for which SSH authentication has to be provided. Could you please help me with this?
I'm using OpenSHH currently, it's ok if I need to change the software

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [su] or [sf].

Comment: If you've got the money, [VShell](https://www.vandyke.com/products/vshell/index.html) pulls this off quite nicely.  *(Not affiliated, just a regular user)*